# Why is the acceleration vector the spatial gradient of the lapse function?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

If we have a Lorentzian manifold $(M, g)$ with a foliation by spacelike surfaces $\Sigma_t$ with unit-normal vector field $n$, we can define the lapse function $N$ by
$$
\partial_t = N n + X
$$
where $X$ is the shift vector. I have seen several claims that, for any $Y$ tangent to $\Sigma_t$, we have
$$
g(\nabla_n n, Y) = \nabla_Y \ln N = N^{-1} \nabla_Y N = N^{-1} Y(N),
$$
but I cannot find a proof for this. It is often stated as a trivial consequence of the definitions but I cannot derive it myself. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla_n n, Y\rangle &= -\langle n, \nabla_Y n\rangle-\langle n, [n,Y]\rangle
\\
&=-\frac 12 Y \langle n,n\rangle - \langle n, N^{-1} Y(N)\rangle
\\
&=N^{-1} Y(N).
\end{align*}
You can get the formula for $[n,Y]$ by writing $n=\frac 1N(\partial_t-X)$ and using the coordinate expression for the Lie bracket.